# What are the Ideal Dimensions for a Reasonably-Sized Studio?

Tags: acoustics, studio, room-treatment

What would be the ideal dimensions; acoustically and logically, to build a free-standing studio?

Say you have a small mixing desk(~30''), two average-sized monitor speakers, a computer + screen (the usual equipment), plus an FX rack, two guitars, two guitar amps and a keyboard stand.

The biggest concern is to have good, clean sound with minimal treatment after it's built.

Comment: Live room or control room? Or both? And money is no object?

Comment: Control room and no.

Comment: As large as possible and shaped something like the floorplans you would see in a [Google image search for "recording studio control room design"](https://goo.gl/TSEoJY). The smaller the room, the more treatment it will need, more or less.